# (NodeJS + Postman) cannot POST

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i have been doing a postman POST request, but i got an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /bookstore</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

here is my POST request code:

```
app.post("/bookstore", (req, res) => {
  const books = req.body;
  db.collection("bookstore")
    .insertOne(books)
    .then((result) => res.json(result))
    .catch((err) => res.send(err));
});
```

GET request is working normally, but when it came to POST, it is giving an error. Please fix my mistake! Thank you...

here is my full code:
db.js

```
    const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
    
    let dbConnection;
    
    module.exports = {
      connectToDb: (cb) => {
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bookstore")
          .then((res) => {
            dbConnection = res.db();
            return cb();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return cb(error);
          });
      },
      getDb: () => dbConnection,
    };
```

and my index.js:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const { connectToDb, getDb } = require("./db");
    const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
    const e = require("express");
    
    // init app and middleware
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.json());
    
    //db connection
    let db;
    
    connectToDb((xato) => {
      if (!xato) {
        app.listen(3000, () => {
          console.log("The 3000 port is installed");
        });
        db = getDb();
        return db;
      }
    });
    
    //routes
    app.get("/bookstore", (req, res) => {
      let mybook = [];
      // the collection name from mongoDB
      db.collection("bookstore")
        .find()
        .sort({ author: 1 })
        .forEach((book) => mybook.push(book))
        .then(() => {
          return res.json(mybook);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          return res.send("there were an error");
        });
      // res.json({ MyWords: "I am coming from json res" });
    });
    
    app.get("/bookstore/:id", (req, res) => {
      if (ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
        db.collection("bookstore")
          .findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) })
          .then((doc) => res.json(doc))
          .catch((err) => res.send(err));
      } else {
        res.send(" wrong id request");
      }
    });
    app.post("/", (req, res) => {
      const books = req.body;
      db.collection("bookstore")
        .insertOne(books)
        .then((result) => res.json(result))
        .catch((err) => res.send(err));
    });
```

I have restarted my express server, but it's still not working

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with that code. Do you have any other routes that might be matching `/bookstore`? If you've recently added the `app.post("/bookstore")` route, have you restarted your Express server?

Comment: i have restarted, but still not working... now i have updated my question with all code files

Comment: it's working now. But i didn't understand what the problem was! it just worked by itself... interesting...